# Unable to get File name of image captured with camera

Tags: camera, uiimagepickercontroller, alassetslibrary, ios8.1

I'm trying to build an app in which I'm able to capture image with camera and save to gallery. But I'm unable to get the file name of image. If I select image from camera roll, then I'm able to get file name of selected image.But when I capture image with camera in my app, It returns file name "`null`". Here is my code to save and select image from gallery using `UIImagePickerController`

```m
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

    UIImage *chosenImage = [self scaleAndRotateImage:[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]];
    NSString *mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
       self.userProfileImage.image = chosenImage;

    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
        UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        if (newMedia)
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,
                                           self,
                                           @selector(image:finishedSavingWithError:contextInfo:),
                                           nil);
    }

    imageRotation=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f %f %f",acos (self.userProfileImage.transform.a), asin (self.userProfileImage.transform.b), atan2(self.userProfileImage.transform.b, self.userProfileImage.transform.a)];
    CGFloat angle = [(NSNumber *)[self.userProfileImage valueForKeyPath:@"layer.transform.rotation.z"] floatValue];
    NSLog(@"%f", angle);

    NSURL *referenceURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
    ALAssetsLibrary *assetLibrary = [ALAssetsLibrary new];

    [assetLibrary assetForURL:referenceURL
                  resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
                      ALAssetRepresentation *assetRep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
                     fileName = [assetRep filename];
                      NSLog(@"File name = %@", fileName);    
                  }

                 failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                     NSLog(@"%@", error);
                 }];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    imageChanged=TRUE;
}
```

And this code to save captured image

```m
- (void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo {
    UIAlertView *alert;
    //NSLog(@"Image:%@", image);
      if (error) {
        alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error!"
                                           message:[error localizedDescription]
                                          delegate:nil
                                 cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                 otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

    }
}
```

I'm stuck at the point that how can I get file name of captured image.
What wrong I'm doing in my code ? Please suggest me any correction or solution. Any help would be appreciated . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I get file name of a file, video or photo, which picked with UIImagePickerController:

```m
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    @try {
        self.myinfo = info;
        DDLogDebug(@"MediaListView - Dismissing camera ui...");
        [self.cameraUI dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

        mediaURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
        DDLogDebug(@"MediaListView - Media url = %@", mediaURL);

        NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
        DDLogDebug(@"MediaListView - Selected mediaType: %@", mediaType);

        // This is a video
        if(mediaURL) {
            DDLogDebug(@"MediaListView - This is a video");

            // Just recorded video
            if (self.source == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {
                DDLogDebug(@"MediaListView - This is a new video, saving to photos album...");

                // Save video before getting its name
                ALAssetsLibrary *library = [ALAssetsLibrary new];

                [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:mediaURL completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
                    if (error) {
                        DDLogDebug(@"MediaListView - Failed to save the photo to photos album...");
                    } else {
                        DDLogDebug(@"MediaListView - Video saved to photos album...");

                        // Video saved, we can get its name
                        [self getNameFromUrl:assetURL];
                    }
                }];
            }
            else {
                DDLogDebug(@"MediaListView - This is an existing video, getting name...");
                // Get video name
                [self getNameFromUrl:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL]];
            }
        }
        // This is a photo
        else {
            DDLogDebug(@"MediaListView - This is a photo...");
            self.originalImage = (UIImage*)[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

            // Just taken photo
            if (self.source == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {
                DDLogDebug(@"MediaListView - This is a new photo, saving to photos album...");

                // Save photo to album
                ALAssetsLibrary *library = [ALAssetsLibrary new];

                [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[self.originalImage CGImage]
                                          orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[self.originalImage imageOrientation]
                                      completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
                    if (error) {
                        DDLogDebug(@"MediaListView - Failed to save the vide to photos album...");
                    } else {
                        DDLogDebug(@"MediaListView - Photo saved to photos album...");

                        // Get photo name
                        [self getNameFromUrl:assetURL];
                    }
                }];
            }
            else {
                DDLogDebug(@"MediaListView - This is an existing image, getting name...");
                // Get photo name
                [self getNameFromUrl:[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"]];
            }
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        DDLogError(@"MediaListView - Exception in picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo");
        DDLogError(@"MediaListView - %@", [exception description]);
    }
}

- (void)getNameFromUrl(NSURL*)url {
    @try {
        DDLogDebug(@"MediaListView - GetNameFromUrl");

        ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *asset) {

            if (asset == nil) {
                DDLogError(@"MediaListView - SaveAssetData - asset is nil!");
                return;
            }

            DDLogDebug(@"MediaListView - SaveAssetData - Got asset data: %@", asset.description);
            ALAssetRepresentation *assetRep = [asset defaultRepresentation];

            NSString *fileName = [assetRep filename];
            DDLogDebug(@"MediaListView - SaveAssetData - File name = %@", fileName);
        };

        ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureblock  = ^(NSError *error) {
            DDLogError(@"MediaListView - SaveAssetData - Failed to get name%@", error);
        };

        ALAssetsLibrary *library = [ALAssetsLibrary new];
        [library assetForURL:url resultBlock:resultblock failureBlock:failureblock];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        DDLogError(@"MediaListView - Exception in saveAssetData");
        DDLogError(@"MediaListView - %@", [exception description]);
    }
}
```

Comment: It didn't work even by shifting dismissing picker to the first line of code block.

Answer (score 0):

[how to get path of picture taken by camera ios swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44522756/how-to-get-path-of-picture-taken-by-camera-ios-swift)

The image you have taken is not saved and has not any name yet. You need to save the image before you can get the path for the image. That´s why it returns nil.